# AWS Console EC2 Cloud Metric Graph not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm having problem with my EC2 Cloud Metric Monitoring. The graph is not showing up in different browsers that I tried (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE). But it's working in my friend's computer.

Do I need to install anything to make it work (e.g: Java, Flash)?

Answer (score 0):

check your browser version. For ideal behavior your browser version should be as per http://aws.amazon.com/console/faqs/ .